# Sign with ECDH using Cryptography API: Next Generation C++

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, cryptography, cryptoapi

[The Signing Data with CNG](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa376304%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) example, shows how to sign and verify using ECDSA.

I changed the code:
BCRYPT_ECDSA_P256_ALGORITHM to BCRYPT_ECDH_P256_ALGORITHM
NCRYPT_ECDSA_P256_ALGORITHM to NCRYPT_ECDH_P256_ALGORITHM

However, the signature verification fails. I can not imagine why it does not work.

I am using Windows 7 64 bits; Visual Studio 2010; Debug; win32 mode.

Articles are very welcome.

Comment: Why would you switch from a digital signature algorithm to a key agreement algorithm in the first place?

Comment: @GregS Perfect, thanks. This is the point. Can you post it as answer!?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ECDH is not a signature algorithm. Therefore, you cannot sign with it.

Comment: What if you try *really really* hard to use it for signing anyway?

Comment: @Jumbogram: if you try hard enough, and I mean *really really really* hard, then it transmutes to ECDSA and will work for signing.

Comment: @Jumbogram Well, sometimes when you run out of API, you do things like using raw RSA to create DH. Thanks for the new word in my dictionary though :)

Comment: @owlstead: You know what that word is from, right?  http://calvinandhobbes.wikia.com/wiki/Transmogrifier